# Проблема с получением значения textarea при передаче post формы

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, form

Есть магазин на `woocommerce` с формой  с текстовым полями и текстовой областью.
В уменьшенном виде выглядит вот так:

```
<form name="checkout" method="post" class="checkout woocommerce-checkout" action="/order" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="text" name="billing_health" value="" placeholder="" required="true">
  <textarea rows="4" name="billing_comments" required="true"></textarea>
</form>
```

Передаю значения на страницу **order**, которые считываю при помощи `$_POST`, которые отправляю в админку. 
С `input` любых типов проблем нет, а вот с `textarea` есть. В `$_POST` значение присутствует, но в текстовую область на стороне **order** оно не записывается и соответственно дальше не передается.

Думал, что возможно, проблему решит функция *htmlspecialchars()*, но тщетно..

В чем причина - не знаю, т.к. если в админке просто меняю вид поля на простой текстовый с тем же именем и настройками - все прекрасно работает.

```
<?php
$fields = WC()->checkout()->get_checkout_fields( 'billing' );
foreach ( $fields as $key => $field ) {
if($key=="billing_comments") {
    if (isset($_POST["$key"])) {
        $comments = htmlspecialchars($_POST["$key"]);
    }
    woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field, $comments );
}
else {
    woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field, $_POST["$key"] );
}
}
?>
```

**UPD**
Самое забавное, что строку

`woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field, $comments );`

изменил на конкретную

`woocommerce_form_field( "billing_health", $fields["billing_health"], $comments );`

с конкретным текстовым полем и **$_POST["$key"]** значение приходящей области в него без проблем записывается, но стоит только поменять на текстовую область в приемнике

`woocommerce_form_field( "billing_comments", $fields["billing_comments"], $comments );`

и все пропадает..
Значит, проблема точно не в отправителе и кодировка верная

Comment: Опять же, добавьте __над__ условием `if ($key == "billing_comments")` вот эту строку: `var_dump($key);`, и запустите код.

Comment: @Эдуард
`string(14) "billing_health"
string(16) "billing_comments"`

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно расшифровал ваш вопрос - у вас не выводится значение поля `textarea` при помощи функции `woocommerce_form_field`? Если так, то смотрим  `woocommerce_form_field`. Единственное упоминание `textarea`:

```
case 'textarea':
        $field .= '<textarea name="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '" class="input-text ' . esc_attr( implode( ' ', $args['input_class'] ) ) . '" id="' . esc_attr( $args['id'] ) . '" placeholder="' . esc_attr( $args['placeholder'] ) . '" ' . ( empty( $args['custom_attributes']['rows'] ) ? ' rows="2"' : '' ) . ( empty( $args['custom_attributes']['cols'] ) ? ' cols="5"' : '' ) . implode( ' ', $custom_attributes ) . '>' . esc_textarea( $value ) . '</textarea>';
```

Value у нас может пропадать только здесь `esc_textarea( $value )`. Смотрим функцию `esc_textarea( $value )`:

```
function esc_textarea( $text ) {
    $safe_text = htmlspecialchars( $text, ENT_QUOTES, get_option( 'blog_charset' ) );
    /**
    * Filters a string cleaned and escaped for output in a textarea element.
    *
    * @since 3.1.0
    *
    * @param string $safe_text The text after it has been escaped.
    * @param string $text      The text prior to being escaped.
    */
    return apply_filters( 'esc_textarea', $safe_text, $text );
}
```

Я думаю, что дело в `$safe_text = htmlspecialchars( $text, ENT_QUOTES, get_option( 'blog_charset' ) );`

Функция объявлена в `wp-includes/formatting.php`. Попробуйте отладит этот момент. Скорее всего проблема в кодировке.

Comment: спасибо за помощь, но не очень похоже, что дело в кодировке. Самое забавное, что строку `woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field, $comments );` изменил на конкретную `woocommerce_form_field( "billing_health", $fields["billing_health"], $comments );` с конкретным текстовым полем и **POST** значение в него без проблем записывается, но стоит только поменять на текстовую область `woocommerce_form_field( "billing_comments", $fields["billing_comments"], $comments );` и все пропадает..

Comment: Я же вам написал, что значение поля textarea, в отличии от значения других полей, обрабатывается функцией esc_textarea. Я вам даже показал, где вы теряете значение.

Comment: Попробовал метод, который описан здесь http://www.marketingextremist.com/how-to-fix-htmlspecialchars-error-after-updating-to-wordpress-3-6-579/
`before: $safe_text = htmlspecialchars( $text, ENT_QUOTES, get_option(‘blog_charset’) );

after: $safe_text = @htmlspecialchars( $text, ENT_QUOTES, get_option(‘blog_charset’) );`
не помогло..

Comment: @Вася, как же можно набрать такой рейтинг на СО и не понимать того, что я пишу? Я что, так непонятно объясняю? Зачениете `$safe_text = htmlspecialchars( $text, ENT_QUOTES, get_option( 'blog_charset' ) );` на `$safe_text = $text`.

Comment: Еще раз попытаюсь - с вероятностью в 99% функция `htmlspecialchars( $text, ENT_QUOTES, get_option( 'blog_charset' ) )` возвращает пустую строку из-за того, что неверно указана кодировка. Кодировка передается последним параметром `get_option( 'blog_charset' ) `. Так тоже непонятно? Еще есть вероятность, что значение теряется здесь `apply_filters( 'esc_textarea', $safe_text, $text )`, но это намного менее вероятно.

Comment: заменил, протестировал вот так`function esc_textarea( $text ) {
 $safe_text = $text;
 return apply_filters( 'esc_textarea', $safe_text, $text );
}` и так `function esc_textarea( $text ) {
 $safe_text = @htmlspecialchars( $text, ENT_QUOTES, get_option( 'blog_charset' ) );
 return apply_filters( 'esc_textarea', $text, $text );
}` результата не дало..

Comment: Сделайте `var_dump($text)` в начале `esc_textarea`,  `var_dump($safe_text)` после `htmlspecialchars` и  `var_dump(apply_filters( 'esc_textarea', $text, $text ))`  - что выводит?

Comment: Там ему больше не где терятся, кроме как в `esc_textarea`.

Comment: все!, нашел косяк в плагине, который фильтровал область вот так `add_filter( 'woocommerce_form_field_textarea'`..)` - там была прописана `esc_attr( $key )` вместо `esc_textarea( $value )`
`$field .= '<textarea rows="4" name="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '"'. ($required ? ' required="true"':'').'>' . esc_textarea( $value ) . '</textarea></p>' . $after;`
Подставил - заработало! Спасибо за помощь. Можете это указать в вашем ответе - я зачту